# Push notification - alert missing from payload

Tags: ios, iphone, apple-push-notifications

This is the `userInfo` I am getting in `didReceiveRemoteNotification`

```
    aps =     {
        badge = 2;
        sound = default;
    };
    u = "{\"custom\":{\"redirectlink\":\"groupdetail.html?groupid=314416&selectedtabid=5\"}}";
}
```

Clearly alert field is missing here. This is what I tried to make to handle missing alert :

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)application didReceiveRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo fetchCompletionHandler:(void (^)(UIBackgroundFetchResult))completionHandler {
   [[UIApplication sharedApplication] setApplicationIconBadgeNumber: 0];
    NSMutableDictionary *pushDict = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:[userInfo objectForKey:@"aps"] ];
    BOOL isSilentPush = [[pushDict objectForKey:@"content-available"] boolValue];
    [pushDict setObject:@"You have a notification" forKey:@"alert"];
    NSMutableDictionary * mut = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithDictionary:userInfo]; //[userInfo copy];
    [mut setObject:pushDict forKey:@"aps"];
    //[mut setObject:@"5@" forKey:@"p"];
    if (isSilentPush) {
        NSLog(@"Silent push notification:%@", userInfo);

        //load content here

        // must call completionHandler
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNewData);
    }
    else {
        [[PushNotificationManager pushManager] handlePushReceived:mut];

        // must call completionHandler
        completionHandler(UIBackgroundFetchResultNoData);
    }
}
```

But this does not generate a **banner** notification. Only badge, sound and alert is generated.
I know this should be handled from server side and not from `iOS` application, but the server guy will be back in 2 days and I have a demo to show.

Comment: The banner is created by iOS prior to your app receiving the notification so it's too late to try to inject an alert message into it. You need your server guy to fix it.

Comment: This PHP problem , you dont create alert filed look at this tutorial http://www.raywenderlich.com/32960/apple-push-notification-services-in-ios-6-tutorial-part-1